# Javascript function onClick doesnt recognize the object

Tags: javascript, jquery

"basic" JS understanding Question;-) I have an JS-function inside the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.shoppinglist-item-add').ShoppinglistItemAdd();
    });
</script>
```

The function "shoppinglistItemAdd" builds dynamicly code like that:

```
 <div class="shoppinglist-item-add" id="XXX" data-setup="{'productId': '456', 'type': 'product', 'large': 'false', 'customProductName': ''}">
....
</div>
```

Now i try to build a function on an other JS File like:

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '.shoppinglist-item-add', function(ev) {
        alert("sali");
    })
```

Unfortunately the second function doesn't work at all. it seems, he doesn't recognize the dynamic build HTML-content from the first function.

I'm not a JS crack, can anyone give me a tip so solve the problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `document.body` instead of simply `'body'`?

Comment: What you have should (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/vgby78vj/) work fine. Check the console for errors

Comment: Is your script in the `<head>`? If so, the `document.body` won't yet exist unless it's in a callback that runs after the `body` is loaded.

Comment: @zurfyx: Why fire up a selector engine when you already have a reference to the element you want?

Comment: Most likely another event is preventing your event from occuring. There's not much you can do about that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.shoppinglist-item-add").bind("click", function(){

        var dataSetup = $(this).attr("data-setup");     

        alert(dataSetup);
    });
});
```